# aws ec2 instances in different vpc subnets access each other

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

I have 2 AWS EC2 instances living inside 2 **different** subnets of my vpc.

I would like to allow the ruby app running on the first instance (say **App#1**) to call the endpoints of the app (say **App#2**) running on the 2nd instance.

I would also like my users to directly call the endpoints of **App#2** from their browser.

---

Here is what I have tried (and mostly failed):

1. [Sucess!] I added the known IP addresses of my users to the *inbound* rules of Load Balancer Security Group of **App#2** and have confirmed that they can access **App#2** endpoints from their browsers.
2. [Fail!] I added the Load Balancer Security Group ID of **App#1** to the *inbound* rules to the Load Balancer Security Group of **App#2**. But my logs tell me **App#1** cannot access the endpoints of **App#2**.
3. [Fail!] I added the VPC Security Group ID of **App#1** to the *inbound* rules of the Load Balancer Security Group of **App#2** - nope, still doesn't work. 
   (Somehow, when I launched the instance for **App#1**, aws automatically created 2 security groups for this instance - one for VPC and one for load balancer... I have no idea why/how this happened...)
4. [Fail!] I added the CIDR for the subnet **App#1** was in to the *inbound* rules of the Load Balancer Security Group of **App#2**. Still no joy.
5. [Success...Sort Of] I assigned an elastic IP for the instance running **App#1** and added that to the *inbound* rules of the Load Balancer Security Group of **App#2**. This works but I would rather not use this method since I would like to elastically scale my **App#1** in the future and I do not know how to automatically assign more elastic IPs for the new instances when they spin up, add them to the *inbound* rules, and then somehow remove them when they shut down.

I feel like there has got to be a really clean solution to this problem and I am probably missing something painfully obvious. Can someone please give me a hint?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using the public IP address of your load balancer, so it looks like the traffic is coming from the outside.  Try using the private IP/DNS if there is one, or setting up a second, internally-facing load balancer.

Comment: Yep you are absolutely right. My team eventually decided to use a different type of authentication/authorization process that gives us more control than the security group setup on AWS so we didn't pursue this question any further. But as far as we observed, yes the traffic was considered coming from the outside even though the instances were all within the same VPC. I will definitely keep your suggestion in mind next time I run into anything like this though! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

So **App#2** is in public subnet, **App#1** is in private subnet. For example, the diagram will be something like:

Internet => LB#2 => App#2:80 (in public subnet) => LB#1 => App#1:4567 (in private subnet)

- Let's open all inbound rules in all instances and loadbalancers, check if you can access it via internet,
- then apply security groups on each layer each time, don't change all of them at same time.

Let me know which layer has issue.